# Relationships in SOSL

Tags: sosl

Can I use relationships in SOSL?

Example: Find all first names that start with 'Roc' within Position__c

```
FIND \'Roc*\' IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Position__c(Id, Contact__r.FirstName WHERE Title__c = 'Paper Jammer')
```

Answer (score 8):

SOSL does not support traversing relationship query .

When you write a query as below

```
List<List<SObject>> searchList = [FIND :mySearchText IN ALL FIELDS 
                          RETURNING 
                             Account (id, name,phone, BillingStreet,BillingCity,BillingState, owner.Alias,owner.MobilePhone )];
```

You will notice that owner.Alias will be null but you will still get ownerId and you can use ownerId to further form queries .

Comment: So is this only on standard relationships? not custom?

Comment: i think it will work for all

Comment: I just checked you still get ownerId and i think you will need to run another query here .I am editing the answer . I still suspect something changed in releases as this answer is nearly three years back .Updating the answer now

Comment: Maybe a bit late to the party, but does this apply to the condition in the "where" clause as well? Is this documented?

Comment: @RenatoOliveira This answer is too old and needs some fresh investigation.  I will ask around internally to see if this is something a known issue or a missing feature or a bug!

Comment: Thank you! In case you do have an answer, I've asked a separate question here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/388208/does-sosl-work-when-there-is-a-criteria-for-filtering-the-searched-object-throug

Comment: FYI I discovered an answer on the Salesforce forums dated from 2009 in which the author of one answer says that the query works if you specify the namespace on the custom objects (for the fields this is not necessary).

Comment: Thanks for closing the loop on this!!