# Does SOSL work when there is a criteria for filtering the searched object through a lookup?

Tags: apex, managed-package, query, sosl

I have a SOSL query that queries on three different objects. A standard and two custom objects. After implementing the `WHERE` clause the query on the standard object is the only part that works. When I try searching for a term that I know for sure that exists in one of the other two, and know that the record meets the criteria, it does not work.

It has been a few hours now, so I don't believe there is an issue to caching (although I am not 100% sure because it is being tested in a scratch org, after all).

Is there any specific limitation on using this criteria on relationship fields?

````sql
List<List<SObject>> result = [
    FIND :searchTerm
    IN ALL FIELDS
    RETURNING
        Object1(
            Id,
            Name
            IsEnabled__c = TRUE),
        Object2(
            Id,
            Name
            WHERE
                Obj1Ref__r.IsActive = TRUE
                AND Obj1Ref__r.IsEnabled__c = TRUE),
        Object3(
            Id,
            Name
            WHERE
                Id IN (
                    SELECT Ref__c
                    FROM OtherObject__c
                    WHERE
                        Ref__r.Obj1Ref__r.IsEnabled__c = TRUE
                ))
    LIMIT :MAX_ROWS
];```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with this query is not using related objects. Those relationships do work.

The problem is that I - also the author of the question - was using the SOSL query in a managed package. That means that the Object2 and Object3 pertained to the package's namespace.

I've read somewhere in an old Salesforce dev forum's answer (dated from 2009!) that the SOSL works in a bit different way than SOQL in Apex compiled code. It seems that for the SOSL to work you have to add the namespace of the package as well. In my case that would mean adding `ns__` to the `Object2` and `Object3`, as in:

```
FIND :term
IN ALL FIELDS
RETURNING
Object1(Id, Name WHERE [condition]),
ns__Object2(Id, Name WHERE [condition]),
ns__Object3(Id, Name, Summary__c WHERE [condition]),
LIMIT :MAX_ROWS
```

Note: in my case `Object1` is a standard object, so this is why it worked with that object but not the other two.